# C# CodeDom Convert between types

Tags: c#, types, codedom

I am trying to use CodeDom to produce the following line of code:

```
object o = (object)bytes
```

**Where "bytes" represents a byte array: byte[] bytes = null;**

I could use the VariableDeclaration method or possibly even the CodeAssign method to generate the *left* side of this line, but how can I create the right side of this line?

I am open to any suggestions - thank you!

Evan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That form of conversion is called casting. Conversion means something along the lines of `Convert.ToInt32("123")`, or `int.Parse("123")`.

**Cast** (*Your exact line* `object o = (object)bytes;`)

```
var declaration = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement()
{
    Name = "o",
    Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(object)),
    InitExpression = new CodeCastExpression(typeof(object), new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("bytes"))
};
```

**Convert** (*My conversion sample* `object o = Convert.ToInt32("123")`)

```
var declaration = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement()
{
    Name = "o",
    Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(object)),
    InitExpression = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
        new CodeTypeReferenceExpression(typeof(Convert)),
        "ToInt32",
        new CodePrimitiveExpression("123"))
};
```